# Trying to Select a Row of data in my tableview to edit

Tags: java, mysql, tableview, scenebuilder

I want to be able to select any row, just 1 row specifically and edit its data.

The data is in a SQL Table.

I am using tableview with scenebuilder 2.

The Problem: The row I select does not update with new fields. Not sure If it recognizes the selection.

Code is posted Below

Sorry if I am not being fully clear, I will be happy to explain further if needed

```
Connection c;
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
                final int j = i;
                TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                    }
                });

                tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
                System.out.println("Column [" + i + "] ");
            }

            /********************************
             * Data added to ObservableList *
             ********************************/
            while (rs.next()) {
                //Iterate Row
                ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    //Iterate Column
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Row [1] added " + row);
                data.add(row);

            }

            //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
            tableview.setItems(data);
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
        }
```

////SELECT A ROW AND EDIT

```
            String a =(String)tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().toString();

            String query = "UPDATE Frontdesk SET CustomerName = ? , Zip = ? , Make =? , Model=? , PhoneNumber =? WHERE CustomerName =? ";
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = c.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, txtCus);
            preparedStmt.setString(2, txtzi);
            preparedStmt.setString(3, txtMod);
            preparedStmt.setString(4, txtMak);
            preparedStmt.setString(5, txtPun);
            preparedStmt.setString(6, a);

            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

This is a screenshot of the application:

[image: This is a screenshot of the application]

Comment: dont worry I have preparedStmt.executeUpdate(); called as well

Comment: Yes. Please do.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: I don't think it is recognizing the row I am selecting to edit, because it just doesn't update the table

Comment: Is the database updated? Can you see the changes being made (outside of your application)?

Comment: Nope. I will update the code right now to show my table is being inserted

Comment: dont worry my connection to MySQL is fine

Comment: Anything in the database logs?

Comment: no problems, I can insert data just fine

Comment: Ok, but does it show anything when you execute your statement?

Comment: theirs no errors, but my table is not being edited.

Comment: If i went into my SQL query and manually selected from WHERE CustomerName = "bob" for example, all the names in my data table with the name bob are edited to my edited input.

Comment: And that does work even for UPDATE statements? Because if it does work, I'm guessing your problem lies in your application rather than in the database itself.